# onChange event for Google Maps APIv3 drawing manager

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, shapes

I'm using the GMaps API v 3 [Drawing Manager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager) to let users draw shapes on a map.

I can use the `complete` events to trigger actions when a shape is added to the map (eg. `overlaycomplete` or `polygoncomplete`)-- but I am also allowing the user to edit the completed shapes.

Is there a way to trigger an action when a shape is changed? I can't see any way to fire another function when a shape is modified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

List of editing events can be found here:

[Editable events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#editable_events)

[Dragging events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#dragging_events)

Here is an example how to use it with DrawingManager when a circle's radius has changed:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function () {
    console.log('radius changed');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vvk4d/

You can use the same approach for polygons/rectangles.

Comment: how exactly do I apply this to polygons? There is no radius on polygons and `radius_changed` doesn't work.

Comment: How can I apply this in angular with <ui-gmap-drawing-manager> directive?

Comment: This will not work if you click and edit a shape. It only works on the create (circlecomplete) event.